# CSS cursor style override automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

[Image link- scss style issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgFRC.jpg)

I tried to change cursor style from pointer to default. But when I save the file and reload react app, the style is not changing. Tried to write code but SO keeps showing a message, guess I am doing it wrong.

When I inspect the element, the cursor default stile has been stiked through and a blue tick was appeared near cursor pointer , which was not even in my code.

Please check the image link above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The easiest way to do that is to use a Stack Snippet (icon looks like [<>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) in the toolbar).

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image attached you have a typo, should be `cursor: default` not `dafault`.

If the style is strike-through it means your style got overridden after.
Try to use the `!important` attribute:

`cursor: default !important;`